# How to calculate bandwidth by SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
-----------+------------+-------
 first     | last       | bytes
-----------+------------+-------
1441013602 | 1441013602 | 10
-----------+------------+-------
1441013602 | 1441013603 | 20
-----------+------------+-------
1441013603 | 1441013605 | 30
-----------+------------+-------
1441013610 | 1441013612 | 30
```

which

- 'first' column is switching time of the first packet of a traffic flow
- 'last' column is switching time of the last packet of a traffic flow
- 'bytes' is the volume of the traffic flow.

How can I calculate bandwidth usage for each second from 1441013602 to 1441013612 ?

I want this:

```
1441013602   20 B/s
1441013603   20 B/s
1441013604   10 B/s
1441013605   10 B/s
1441013606    0 B/s
1441013607    0 B/s
1441013608    0 B/s
1441013609    0 B/s
1441013610   10 B/s
1441013611   10 B/s
1441013612   10 B/s
```

Comment: do a left join on `generate_series`, then group and aggregate.

Comment: @CraigRinger, thanks. I don't understand your mean! I should generate a series table of seconds and left join it on which field of traffic table? can you explain more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PostgreSQL's `generate_series` function for this. Generate a series of rows, one for each second, since that's what you want. Then left join on the table of info, so that you get one row for each second for each data flow. `GROUP BY` seconds, and `sum` the data flow bytes.

e.g:

```
SELECT seconds.second, coalesce(sum(t.bytes::float8 / (t.last::float8-t.first::float8+1)),0)
FROM generate_series(
  (SELECT min(t1.first) FROM Table1 t1),
  (SELECT max(t1.last) FROM Table1 t1)
) seconds(second)
LEFT JOIN table1 t
  ON (seconds.second BETWEEN t.first and t.last)
GROUP BY seconds.second
ORDER BY seconds.second;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b3b07/7

Note that we calculate the bytes per second of the flow, then sum that over the seconds of the flow across all flows. This only gives an estimate, since we don't know if the flow rate was steady over the flow duration.

For formatting the bytes, use the `format` function and/or `pg_size_pretty`.

Comment: nice, perhaps more accurate use `avg` instead of **sum** in select clause.

Comment: @danihp Right, because it's bytes across the duration of the flow, not bytes per second. `avg` isn't right, you have to get the bytes per second then `sum`. Fixing.

Answer (score 2):

Here an approach at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a9b0e/16)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t ( first int, last int, bytes int );

insert into t values 
(1441013602 , 1441013602 , 10 ),
(1441013602 , 1441013603 , 20 ),
(1441013603 , 1441013605 , 30 ),
(1441013610 , 1441013612 , 30 );
```

**The query**:

```
with

bytes as
       ( select first, last, 
              ( last - first ) as calc_time,
              bytes
         from t
         where ( last - first )>0 ),

bytes_per_second as 
       ( select first, last, bytes / calc_time as Bs
         from bytes ),

calc_interval as 
       ( SELECT * FROM generate_series(1441013602,1441013612) )

select 
       i.generate_series, bps.Bs
  from 
       calc_interval i 
  left outer join
       bytes_per_second bps 
          on i.generate_series between bps.first and bps.last - 1
 order by 
       i.generate_series
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a9b0e/16/0)**:

```
| generate_series |     bs |
|-----------------|--------|
|      1441013602 |     20 |
|      1441013603 |     15 |
|      1441013604 |     15 |
|      1441013605 | (null) |
|      1441013606 | (null) |
|      1441013607 | (null) |
|      1441013608 | (null) |
|      1441013609 | (null) |
|      1441013610 |     15 |
|      1441013611 |     15 |
|      1441013612 | (null) |
```

Explanation:

- **bytes** and **bytes_per_second** are to cleaning data, perhaps is more accurate to do an average.
- **calc_interval** a generator for your seconds.
- **last select** is the final calculation. Also joining generated seconds with bandwidth.

Comment: Using a CTE like this is tempting for clarity, but unfortunately a PostgreSQL misfeature means the query planner can't optimize across CTE terms properly. You're generally better off using subqueries in the `FROM` clause, even though it's horrid.